Can I get the Windows Logon Username if I am authenticating using entity framework (Application ID Not Windows ID)
Lets say my windows login is user1@domain1   but I am logging into an .Net 7 Core application using a username and password that are not connected to my domain (webuser1).  Is it possible in any way (even if its being gathered in the client and being passed to server) that I can get Windows Logon Name for webuser1?
Obviously the User.Identity is going to be the application users information (webuser1).  What I would like to know is that User1@Domain is logged into the app as webuser1.  User1@Domain is also logged into the app as webuser2.
This is sort of a left over requirement from when the client was a thick client where getting the domain users identity was pretty simple.  Now that it has moved to web it is probably impossible but I wanted to check if anyone has a solution.

There is no direct way to access the client's Windows login information from the server or through standard client-side JavaScript due to security and privacy restrictions imposed by web browsers. there is way with the custom client side scripting that interacts with a local service running on the user’s machine. This local service could access the Windows username and then pass it back to the web application but it is not recommended.

You could also create custom authentication, once user try to login using the web user, you can suggest user provider their windows login name, and then store them in database or other.
